# how to assign the value returned from function call to a variable inside html in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodelchange

```
<select [(ngModel)]="country" (change)="stateList = getStateList(country)">
        <option *ngFor="let c of countryList" [value]="c.Country.CountryID"></option>
</select>
```

Here in (ngModelChange) I want to assign the value returned from getStateList() to a varible, but it just calls the function and the return value is not bound to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply assign inside the getStateList function itself

```
<select [(ngModel)]="country" (change)="getStateList(country)">
        <option *ngFor="let c of countryList" [value]="c.Country.CountryID"></option>
</select>
```

inside the component

```
getStateList(country : any){
   this.stateList = (getData);

}
```

Comment: But i want to temporarily create stateList for each div, and number of divs is dynamic, so it will not be usable

Comment: then return the stateList

Comment: But i want to save each stateList value as well

Comment: Can you please show me how to do, as i am new here, thank you

Comment: its too broad, you can maintain a variable stateList inside the country object and assign it whenever you need

Comment: hope you goit it sorted